# Learn python hard way ex.43. Syntax

Tags: python, class, oop, dictionary, syntax

Quick question on syntax in this exercise;I tried searching for it thinking it would be a popular question, but nothing! So I'm probably just confused. Anyhow looking at the below code excerpts:

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter()




class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Wouldn't the `play()` result in a syntax that would state:

`current_scene = CentralCorridor().enter()`

I mean the code works but I would believe in order for the code to work the syntax should be

`current_scene = CentralCorridor.enter()`

Is there something I'm overlooking when it comes to key/values as functions?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the definition of `enter` inside `CentralCorridor`. If `enter` has a first parameter (which is by convention, called self, but could be named anything really), then you need to pass in a parameter.

In Python when an *instance* of a class calls a method of the class, it implicitly passes a reference to itself as the first positional argument.

So with a call like `CentralCorridor.enter()`, you are passing in 0 arguments and you will get a `TypeError` saying that you are missing one required positional argument. And with a call like `CentralCorridor().enter()`, you are implictly passing in the new instance you create as the first parameter to the method `enter`. This is just a shorthand way of writing:

`CentralCorridor.enter(CentralCorridor())`